# How can I change the public IP address?

Tags: ip-address, ip

I have Kubuntu 12.04 installed on dual boot with Windows 7, when I search  for my IP on Google, I get different results: one IP for Windows 7, and other for Kubuntu (it says also no proxy detected)

I was banned from a certain webpage, they say that my user account is banned as well as my computer. I can't enter with other newly created accounts, but with kubuntu, I can enter with no problems (not same banned account, but the same computer, that means they banned the IP address only).

How can I change my IP address on Kubuntu to another, in case they detect that is the same computer, or I get banned again? I am using default network manager.

I receive internet from a router with DCHP enabled, and other computers connected to the router. On Windows 7 I sometimes use the virtual wifi miniport to share internet with a laptop and that laptop gets different IP addresses each time I create the network.

Comment: maybe `ifconfig eth0 ip netmask gateway dns`???

Comment: The IP that appears as your public address on the Internet is in most cases the one that on the terminal equipment for your internet connection, from your internet provider. E.g, if you have a DSL connection, that device will be your modem. That IP address is usually different than the one on your PC/laptop, which is a private one.

If what you need is to change your public IP, you might be able to do that by restarting your modem, depending on whether or not your provider leases you a dynamic IP, and also depending on how often they renew their leases.

Comment: Your public IP depends on the internet provider (ISP), and in most cases, you can't change it at will.

Comment: I reinstalled Windows 7,installed kubuntu on dual-boot, and both of them have different Ip addresses, different from the last ones. How can I change Ip without formatting?

Comment: They may be different every time. If you are having gripes with a site, I recommend you contact the site owner directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a "public IP", this suggests you have a different IP in your local network. That usually means you have something like a broadband modem/router, which is often NATed just to make things more interesting. In that case, it's the router that owns the public IP and you cannot change it in either Ubuntu, Windows or any other OS.

You should contact your internet service provider to get answers to this question.

Comment: I am in a network wich uses a router and there are other several PCs. When I search in google ''my ip'', it shows an address, if I reinstall the OS, I get a different address in google, but I guess the router still has its unchangeable ip. I want to change only what my computer ip is, without reinstalling OS, because that is enough to avoid bans.

Comment: For the record... Some ISPs se a proxy system to save bandwith. It's possible to get different ip results depending on "who" you ask.